# correct way of deleting items in collection view

Tags: ios, arrays, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view of 20 items stored in pictures array. I am deleting selected items with this code:

```
            self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            let selectedItems = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
            self.picturesObject.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(selectedItems)
            self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(selectedItems)

            }, completion: {_ in})
```

this is the implementation of picturesObject's deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:

```
func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths:[NSIndexPath]){
        for indexPath in indexPaths{
            pictures.removeAtIndex(indexPath.item)
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is the following. Every time a selected item in collection view is deleted, the pictures array gets smaller. If I delete the first item, than pictures array is only 19 items big. If I than try to delete item number 20 in collection view, the array index gets out of bounds because pictures array is now only 19 object big, but I wanted to delete the 20iest object stored in indexpath.item.

**What is the correct way of deleting items in collection view?**

EDIT:/// collection view methods

```
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return picturesObject.pictures.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ShopCell
        cell.imageView.image = picturesObject.pictures[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i think you delete the image in your array but your dataSource delegate methode keep 20 items in memory. Can you paste your collectionView delegate methods?

Comment: There you go. I edited my question. I think they are datasource methods, don't have any others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before looping through your array in `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`, sort your `indexPaths` in descending order.  Then, if you delete item number 19, the next to delete is guaranteed to be less than 19.

Comment: I'm not sure if understand. Can you provide example? Shouldn't I somehow update indexPaths of cells in collectionView? I am also deleting multiple selected items at the same time.

Comment: You have 20 items numbered 0-to-19.  If you delete 0 first, then deleting 19 will crash because it's not there anymore.  If you delete 19 first, everything is fine when you delete 0.  So, if you sort `indexPaths` so that looping through them uses higher values of `indexPath.item` before lower ones, you avoid the problem.